# use PictureBox from another class c#

Tags: c#, class

I hope my question will be clear

In Form1.cs i have PictureBox named: ico_ok

i would like to use this PictureBox in my new class that i bulit.
when i start typing ico... nothing appears.
what is the way to use this object in another class?

here the code:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_check.Visible = true;
        btn_continue.Visible = false;
        txtbox_cusnumber.Enabled = false;
        string userID = (txtbox_cusnumber.Text.ToString());

        CheckOUinADexist checkou = new CheckOUinADexist(userID);
    }
```

after that look at the new class:

```
namespace ChekingOUinActiveDirectory
```

{

```
      class CheckOUinADexist
      {

              public CheckOUinADexist(string userID)
              {
              //this place i would like to use ico_ok
              }

 }
```

}

Thank you for helping.
Maayan

Comment: Don't.  Pass data around, but not gui controls.  If a PictureBox control is on a form, it's best that it stays there.  Maybe add another parameter to `CheckOUinADexist(string userID, Image image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to provide that class with the dependency on the `PictureBox`:

```
public CheckOUinADexist(string userID, PictureBox pbox)
{
    pbox.[your code]
}
```

Then supply it when calling the method:

```
CheckOUinADexist checkou = new CheckOUinADexist(userID, ico_ok);
```

Whether or not this is the *ideal* approach depends on what you're going to be *doing* with that `PictureBox` inside that object, how portable that object needs to be across technology platforms, etc.

In general you don't want UI elements to permeate into non-UI logic.  If `CheckOUinADexist` is a UI-bound class and exists solely to help the UI, then this isn't a problem.  If it's part of business logic then you wouldn't want to couple that logic with the UI technology.  Instead, you'd likely pass it the *data* needed from the `PictureBox`, but not the `PictureBox` itself.

This all depends a lot on the overall architecture of what you're trying to achieve here, which we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'd give the target class a reference to the "shared data" -- picture box in this case.

```
class CheckOUinADexist
{
    PictureBox _picBox
    public CheckOUinADexist(string userID, PictureBox picBox)
    {
        //this place i would like to use ico_ok
        _picBox = picBox;
        _picBox.myAction();
    }
}
```

Whether you want to actually stored `Picturebox` as a field (as opposed to just use a parameter) depends on whether you need access to the field throughout the lifetime of the instance(s) or whether it is just needed for object construction. If you are not sure, you are safer (IMHO) just storing a reference in a field. Make further uses of it a lot easier.